# AJAX call doesn't complete and throws TypeError: undefined has no properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The following JavaScript code calls an ASP.NET controller action and is supposed to fill an element with the returned PartialView. Instead it throws an error in the browser console 'TypeError: undefined has no properties'. This is obviously very vague and I'm not sure how to move forward. While debugging, I see that it will run up to the success/fail portion of the AJAX call, pass over the success/fail, try the AJAX call again, then throw the error.

```
$(".form-module").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var thisForm = $(this);
    if (formIsSetupProperly(thisForm) === false) {
        return;
    }
    var formSubmitButton = Ladda.create(thisForm.find(".form-module-submit-button")[0]);
    formSubmitButton.toggle();

    var controller = $(this).data("controller");
    var action = thisForm.data("action");
    var method = thisForm.data("method");
    var serializedForm = thisForm.serialize();
    $(this).validate();
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        cache: false,
        data: serializedForm,
        url: "/" + controller + "/" + action,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.isError === true) {
                console.error(data.message.Text);
                $(".clear-on-error").val("");
                thisForm.addClass("has-error");
                thisForm.find(".form-module-error").html(data.message.Text);
                formSubmitButton.toggle();
            } else if (data.isRedirect === true) {
                window.location = data.message.Url;
                formSubmitButton.toggle();
            } else {
                thisForm.closest("#wizard").html(data).promise().done(function () {
                    var thisFormCallback = thisForm.data("callback");
                    if (thisFormCallback !== undefined) {
                        eval(thisFormCallback + "()");
                    }
                });
                ajax_loader_init();
            }

        },
        fail: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            formSubmitButton.toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

[image: Console error message]
[image: Offending code snippet]

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: `eval(thisFormCallback + "()");` ugh! How about `window[thisFormCallback]()` instead.

Comment: @Barmar it will go to line 19 (url: "/" + controller + "/" + action,) and then pass over the success/fail block, and then go back to line 14 to retry to AJAX call before finally throwing an error to the console

Comment: The error message occurs on the line `$(this).validate()`? What validation plugin are you using? Is that `jquery-validate` or part of ASP.NET?

Comment: No, it occurs on line 19... `url: "/" + controller + "/" + action,`

Comment: That makes no sense. That line doesn't access any object properties, it just concatenates strings. What is the exact error message?

Comment: The exact error message is : "TypeError: undefined has no properties"

Comment: What are the values of `controller` and `action`?

Comment: controller is `Login` and action is `StepUsernameValidation`, both of which are valid controllers and actions.

Comment: There's nothing undefined on that line, I don't believe it's really where the error is happening. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I added screenshots to the original post

Comment: The screenshot says that the error is happening on line 1218 of `jquery.validate.js`, not in your code.

Comment: You're missing the argument to `$(this).validate()`, which specifies all the validation options. You also shouldn't be calling this in the `submit` handler. It's normally called in your `$(document).ready()` function, and it establishes its own submit handler that performs validation and submits the form for you.

Comment: If you want to do AJAX submission, you provide your function as the `submitHandler:` option to `.validate()`.